# How to show on a transparent part of an image the image that lays behind it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNIk3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqDeF.png)

I got a screen sketch from our designer which includes a menu with two buttons which are images basically, when one button is continued into a triangle cut of the other.
I tried to create an image with a transparent triangle a put the to images in a Stack widget, but the transparent triangle is shown black and not a part of the red image as I would expect.
I want the red image that lays behind it to be shown on that part. There is my code :

```
Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MenuButton(
                      buttonText: Constants.X,
                      destinationScreen: X.id,
                      backgroundImage: "red_check.jpg",
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 170.0,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 320,
                        height: 170,
                        child: MenuButton(
                          buttonText: Constants.Y,
                          destinationScreen: Y.id,
                          backgroundImage: "yellow_check.png",
                          bCover: false,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

class MenuButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String buttonText;
  final String destinationScreen;
  final String backgroundImage;
  final bool bCover;

  MenuButton(
      {this.buttonText,
      this.destinationScreen,
      this.backgroundImage = '',
      this.bCover = true});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                (Utils.getString(context, buttonText)),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
              ),
            ),
            width: 120,
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(Constants.IMAGES_PATH + backgroundImage),
                  fit: bCover ? BoxFit.cover : BoxFit.fill),
              // button text
            )),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, destinationScreen);
        });
  }
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BoxDecoration` you've specified has a black background:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                (Utils.getString(context, buttonText)),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
              ),
            ),
            width: 120,
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black, //  I'M HERE
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(Constants.IMAGES_PATH + backgroundImage),
                  fit: bCover ? BoxFit.cover : BoxFit.fill),
              // button text
            )),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, destinationScreen);
        });
  }
```

Just set the `BoxDecoration` color to `Colors.transparent` or do not specified it at all (the default is `Colors.transparent`), like so:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                (Utils.getString(context, buttonText)),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
              ),
            ),
            width: 120,
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent, // FIXED
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(Constants.IMAGES_PATH + backgroundImage),
                  fit: bCover ? BoxFit.cover : BoxFit.fill),
              // button text
            )),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, destinationScreen);
        });
  }
```